# Go: How to pretty print nested objects with pointers values?

Tags: go

How can I pretty print the object below?

```
package main

// OBJECT: {
//   TABLE: {
//     files: [],
//     data: {
//        CODE: {
//          name: "NAME",
//          count: 123,
//       }
//     }
//
// }

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type Container map[string]*Table

type Table struct {
    files []string
    data  map[string]*Data
}

type Data struct {
    name  string
    count int
}

func main() {

    object := Container{
        "table1": {
            files: []string{"file-1.1"},
            data: map[string]*Data{
                "XYZ": {
                    name:  "foo",
                    count: 123,
                },
            },
        },
        "table2": {
            files: []string{
                "file-2.1",
                "file-2.2",
                "file-2.3",
            },
        },
        "table3": {files: []string{"file-3.1"}},
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", &object)
    objectJSON, err := json.MarshalIndent(object, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", objectJSON)

}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/FRWZsfwgyNU

With this code, I'm only getting the first depth of my object:

```
&main.Container{"table1":(*main.Table)(0xc00005c020), "table2":(*main.Table)(0xc00005c040), "table3":(*main.Table)(0xc00005c060)}
{
  "table1": {},
  "table2": {},
  "table3": {}
}

Program exited.
```

Comment: You can have those pointer types implement the `Stringer` interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't about "depth". You can't generically pretty-print private, un-exported fields using `fmt.Printf` or `json.Marshal`. If you want the variable to appear when marshling, export them (ie, change `Table.files` to `Table.Files`. Go will marshal exported fields to arbitrary depth:

```
{
  "foo1": {
    "Files": [
      "file-1.1"
    ],
    "Data": {
      "XYZ": {
        "Name": "foo",
        "Count": 123
      }
    }
  },
  "foo2": {
    "Files": [
      "file-2.1",
      "file-2.2",
      "file-2.3"
    ],
    "Data": null
  },
  "foo3": {
    "Files": [
      "file-3.1"
    ],
    "Data": null
  }
}
```

If you want to pretty print the object using `fmt.Printf("%v", ...)` then you need to implement the `Stringer` interface on each of your class. At that point, the decision about how to print the object is *entirely* up to you and you can include public or private members in whatever format you'd like.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How come that converting to capital the first letter has so much impact ?

Comment: Capitalization is visibility.`Foo` is public. `foo` is private.